# How do I set up dependencies in vscode C++ with or without CMake? (Target lib is glfw)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, dependencies, glfw

I am trying to set up an glfw project in vscode and I can't seem to get the dependencies working. I can't find anything that helps me on the web.

This is my main.cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Classes/BaseStructs.h"
#include "Dependencies/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"


int main(){
    if (!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "GLFW did not initialize." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(GameEngine)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

include_directories(src/Dependencies/include/GLFW)

add_executable(GameEngine ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(GameEngine src/Dependencies/lib-mingw)
```

My include paths (UI):

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
${workspaceFolder}/src/Classes
${workspaceFolder}/src/Dependencies/include/GLFW
${workspaceFolder}/src/Dependencies/lib-mingw
```

I put the dependencies folder in the src folder because that seems like the only way I can "access" the glfw functions. Intellisense recommends functions like glfwInit() and I don't get any warnings. But whenever I try to run the main.cpp file, I get this error:
`C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4OwRzb.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to` glfwInit'`

I am new to this so please explain what you're doing and why if you know the solution.

Comment: When you google this, don't google specifically about VSC. Figure out how to compile from the terminal first, and once you get that to work, having VSC run the same commands should be simple.

Comment: For solve "undefined reference" error you need to **link** with GLFW library. You current code links only with `src/Dependencies/lib-mingw`, which doesn't look like a that library. (But it looks like a **directory**, so you probably got a warning from CMake or from the linker).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you know what library I have to use (from the glfw pre-compiled windows version) for vscode using mingw as a compiler? Because it says lib-mingw, which I suppose is meant to be short for library.

Comment: Link with either `libglfw3.a` or `libglfw3.dll.a`. The first one is a static library, the second one is shared (so it will require `glfw3.dll` at runtime). When specify a **path** in `target_link_libraries` call, make sure that given path is **absolute**. You may refer to the directory with the currently processed `CMakeLists.txt` via `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.